# Error when running application at the container -Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

```
Command: $ docker run -p 8080:3000 -v $(pwd):/var/www node -w "/var/www" node npm start
```

> Error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused
>   "exec: \"-w\": executable file not found in $PATH" C:\Program
>   Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: oci
>   runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process
>   caused "exec: \"-w\": executable file not found in $PATH".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got it working.
But Please tell me whether I am correct.
I have changed from H:/ to C:/Users/myfolder directory and ran the code again. This time it worked.

Should we be in the C directory to run the code successfully?